# NumberFormatException:Invalid lng

Tags: java, android, client-server

Hi guys i am currently doing a client server application using DH key exchange in android.
I am having problems converting a string into long on my client side, the strange thing is that the conversion worked for the first 2 variables pValue and gValue. However, when i wanted to convert the server`s public key when it is sent over from the server. I get a number format exception : invalid long.
I am pretty sure that the number sent over is a numerical number and not an alphabet as i printed them out in strings.
The server sends the gValue:pValue:PK together which is separated by a :

Below is my code snippet for my client side.

```
try {

   response = SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8000/MyServletProject/DHServlet");
   String res = response.toString(); 

   String  [] ar = res.split(":");
   String primeValue = ar[0];
   String genValue = ar[1];
   String pkSValue = ar[2];
   System.out.println(pkSValue);
   long convertPValue = Long.parseLong(primeValue);
   long convertGValue = Long.parseLong(genValue);
   long convertSValue = Long.parseLong(pkSValue);
   //BigInteger biPK;
   // biPK = new BigInteger(pkSValue);
   //System.out.println(convertPKValue);
   long skB=getDH.generateSKB();

   BigInteger bi1,bi2,bi3,sKey,biSK;

   bi1=BigInteger.valueOf(convertGValue);
   bi2=BigInteger.valueOf(convertPValue);
   bi3=getDH.generatePkB(bi1, bi2, skB);
   biSK = BigInteger.valueOf(skB);
   //biPK= new BigInteger(pkSValue);
   String PKClient = bi3.toString();
   System.out.println("The public key is "+PKClient);
   System.out.println("The generator value is "+bi1);
   System.out.println("The prime value is "+bi2);
```

LogCat

```
07-12 12:24:33.459: I/System.out(2387): 4126158 
07-12 12:24:33.459: W/System.err(2387): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "4126158 
07-12 12:24:33.479: W/System.err(2387): "
07-12 12:24:33.489: W/System.err(2387):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
07-12 12:24:33.499: W/System.err(2387):     at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
07-12 12:24:33.499: W/System.err(2387):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
07-12 12:24:33.529: W/System.err(2387):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
07-12 12:24:33.529: W/System.err(2387):     at com.example.firstapp.clientside.LoginLayout$1$1.run(LoginLayout.java:70)
07-12 12:24:33.549: W/System.err(2387):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-12 12:25:55.460: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2387): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-12 12:28:54.453: I/System.out(2437): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2810970
```

I am really stumped on this , hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using BigInteger? isnt this the same as a long?

Comment: I`m using big integer as my public keys will go up to an arbitrary amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this line

```
07-12 12:24:33.459: I/System.out(2387): 4126158
```

It seems that you have a space at the end of `4126158`.

You can use the java.lang.String.trim() to trim the string before trying to parse it to `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Strings have carriage returns/new lines in them which is throwing off the parsing.

You can try sanitising the data first like so:

```
try {
    primeValue = primeValue.trim();
    long convertPValue = Long.parseLong(primeValue);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace()
}
```

Also, you really should be checking for these errors by trying to catch the Exception.

If you own the server you can also look at changing the output accordingly but you should still assume anything the client gets can be garbage and fail gracefully :)

Answer (score 0):

the returned value is `"4126158` and the `"` is redundant so compiler can't convert that value to a number type

Answer (score 0):

```
07-12 12:24:33.459: W/System.err(2387): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "4126158 
07-12 12:24:33.479: W/System.err(2387): "
```

There is a line break in your String. Make sure your server doesn't send the String with a line break at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without more details, but maybe there is some whitespace/line break at the end of the string? Try

```
pkSValue = pkSValue.trim().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
```

Comment: yes you are right. There was a spacing in the number, that was causing the exception